# Backquote keystroke won't work on Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

On my tilde key (near the number one key), there is another symbol, the back quote. Whenever I hold down Shift and press that key, I do not get a back quote typed out.

[image: Image. A photo of a Corsair keyboard with a red circle around one key. The key is just to the left of the number 1 key along the top number row. The key circled has a tilde on the lower half, then a back quote on the upper half.]

I have looked at an article previously where you open up Text Services and Input Languages on the computer:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows dialog box titled Text Services and Input Language. There are two tabs marked Language Bar and Advanced Key Settings, with the Advanced Key Settings tab selected. Among the other controls available in this tab, there is a button link at the bottom titled Change Key Sequence...]

You then open up Change Sequence Key:

[image: Image. A screenshot of a Windows dialog box titled Change Key Sequence. Two controls with several radio buttons are shown. The controls are titled Switch Input Language and Switch Keyboard Layout respectively. Each has four radio button options. These options include Not Assigned, Control plus Shift, Left Alt plus Shift, and Grave Accent. Switch Input Language has its Control plus Shift radio button marked, while Switch Keyboard Layout has its Not Assigned radio button marked]

And when I changed to Not Assigned and apply, it does nothing. Is there anyway I can activate my back quote symbol?

Comment: @DanielB I have fixed my question, sorry.

Comment: Alright! What happens if after pressing the backtick key, you press _A_? Or _Space_?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry for not clarifying more, yea i press another key after pressing that and nothing happens. I honestly dont know if its a software problem or its my keyboard itself,.

Comment: Strange. But in the first place, on a US keyboard, you get a backtick when _not_ pressing Shift and a tilde when you do. What keyboard layout are you using? Please provide the full name (like "US International"). Are you using any tools for remapping keys?

Comment: @DanielB I do not know if I am using any tools for remapping keys, so i'd assume not. AS for the Us keyboard layout it is a QWERTY US.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a keyboard that has built-in macro and/or key mapping functionality? Fancy gaming keyboards often have this.